# Create a Tables of signs and variations of function using tkz-tab package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a serious problem to solve. I would like to make a function monotonicity in my latex doc and i write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,
->,
> = latex’,
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=5]{$x$ /1, $\ln x +1$ /1.5, $x \ln x$ /2}%
{$0$ ,$1/\E$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{d,-,z,+,}
\tkzTabVar%
{ D+/ / $0$ ,%
-/ \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{$\dfrac{-1}{e}$}}/ ,%
+/ $+\infty$ / }%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it shows error. Is something with any package or some setting i have to to in the doc??

---

[image: example]

I sent you an exact example of what i try to do

Comment: Is it possible that you complete the code snippet to a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)?

Comment: There is no package `tikzpicture` … What Thorsten wrote: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. The problem is different. Here it's a bad use of the package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly it's preferable to give a complete example, then you need to define `\E`, you need to load [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=5]{$x$ /1, $\ln x +1$ /1.5, $x \ln x$ /2}{$0$ ,$1/\E$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{d,-,z,+,}
\tkzTabVar%
{ D+/ / $0$ ,%
-/ \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{$\dfrac{-1}{e}$}}/ ,+/ $+\infty$ / }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i manage the follow example?? It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: We do appreciate if the package author writes the manual in English!