# Monotonicity tabular latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I repost my question. I try to succeed the following table in my latex doc.[image]

I have done the first 3 lines but i cannot do the curve arrows in the forth line.I sent you the code until now

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $f'(x)$ /1.5, $f''(x)$ /2,$f(x)$/2.5}{$-\infty$, $0$ ,$1$ , $2$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,+,z,- ,d,-,z,+}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,-,t ,- ,d,+,t ,+}%
\tkzTabVar%
{ -/  ,  +/ ,-D+/  /  ,  -/  ,+/  /  }%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Please indicate in your question that this is a follow-up to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162157/create-a-tables-of-signs-and-variations-of-function-using-tkz-tab-package.

Comment: You don't seem to be trying to reproduce quite the same thing since your first 3 lines don't match that image yet you say that those are OK. Am I missing something?

Comment: I managed to make the first 3 lines with the values of x, the first and the second derivative and i try ta drw the curve arrows. What do you mean "since your first 3 lines don't match that image". It is not the same example as mine, ofcourse, but if i had the table on my doc i wouldn't post it here. The thing is the last line. I can manage straight arrows but i cannot the curved as the image i sent. Is it clear what i try to do?

Comment: Please don’t post the same question multiple times. If you have a specific follow-up question, be concise about what exactly your problem is and, like cfr noted, add a link to the original question. If none of the answers on the original question conform to your vision you could also put a bounty on it, to attract more attention.